# post_save doesn't list tags

Tags: django, django-taggit

Idea is to use a post_save signal to do things if an object has certain tags, but the tags are not being listed

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=List)
def list_saved(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        for tag in instance.tags.all():
            print(tag.name)
```

This never lists any tags, it's an empty query set.
Yet if I then open the shell and do:

```
>>> l = List.objects.filter(pk=1).get()
>>> for tag in l.tags.all():
>>>   print(tag.name)
```

It works fine.

Why are the tags not available in the post_save?

Tags are added to list as such:

```
class List(models.Model):
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `tags` is a `ManyToManyField` at the heart of it. If that's the case, then when you create a `List` instance it won't have any `tags` set. You'll need to connect to the [`m2m_changed` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.m2m_changed) to determine the changes in the `tags` collection.

Comment: That was it. Thanks!